# python 2.7 else SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-2.7

Have you see any problem for this Python code?
in line 6 it may have a problem but I can't figure it.

```
def tesla (x,y) :
  if x > y : 
      return "1" 
  elif x == y : 
      return 0
  else x < y : 
      return -1

print "enter x and y: \n"
x = int(raw_input ("enter x: "))
y = int(raw_input ("enter y: "))

a = tesla (x,y)
print a
```

the error:

```
  File "training_1.py", line 6
    else x < y :
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What are you expecting that line to do? `else` isn't followed by anything, it's what is called if all the other conditions fail.

Comment: Totally unrelated, but in the first `if` branch you certainly want to return `1` (int, no quotes), not `"1"` (string).

Answer (score 2):

because `else` has to be lonely there (meaning that nothing is right), so maybe `elif` again:

```
def tesla (x,y) :
  if x > y : 
      return "1" 
  elif x == y : 
      return 0
  elif x < y : 
      return -1
```

But in this case can be direct `else` because no other cases that could happen:

```
def tesla (x,y) :
  if x > y : 
      return "1" 
  elif x == y : 
      return 0
  else: 
      return -1
```

Comment: thanks for your help